# Best restfull way to create a child item from parent item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As a newbie, I have been searching around for THE best practice to create a child item when displaying a parent item. I found many explanations, rather incomplete and not evident to me. Can some one describe the complete implementation of the best practice ?
I created `parent_item` and `child_item` models includind `has_many` and `belongs_to` declarations.
I can list linked `child_items` (manually created) in the `parent_item` "show" view.

Now I'd like to create a `<%= link_to 'New Child Item', new_child_item_path %>` passing parent's id as a parameter in the URL.
Which way to go now ?

- modify the routes ?
- add a parameter to `child_item.new` controller ?
- have a hidden field in the child_item form to store the `parent_item.id` value ?

I'll be glad to give a hug to the best explanation !

Thanks !

Fred

---

Hi, thanks for your help. As I'm discovering this nesting resources functionality, I tried to apply it with success : when creating the child from the parent, the form is displayed with the parent_id that has been passed to it.

Here are my code updates : (playground is the parent, landscape is the child)

**ROUTES**

```
resources :playgrounds do
  resources :landscapes, :only=>[:new, :create]
end
```

**SHOW** (from playground parent)

```
  <%= link_to 'Add landscape', new_playground_landscape_path(@playground) %>
```

**LANDSCAPE_CONTROLLER**

```
def new
  @landscape = Landscape.new
  @landscape.playground_id = params[:playground_id]
```

**FORM** (from landscape) - I did not need to refer to @playground as I only have landscape fields in this form (Am I right ?)

```
<%= form_for [@landscape] do |f| %>
...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :playground_id %><br />
    <%=f.text_field :playground_id%>
  </div>
```

Great, it works fine. But the playground_id field should not appear in the form, and be defined as not accessible attribute in the landscape.rb model. 
Are these requirements compatible ?
Shall I hide the field, and leave it accessible ?

Thanks for your help !

Fred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a clear-cut case for nested resources. In that, you'll pass your parent resource to the generated path helper.

```
resources :parents do 
  resources :children
end
```

In this case, you'll end up with a path helper that look like

```
new_parent_child_path(@parent)
```

In your child controller, the parent object will be in params as `:parent_id`

```
def show
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
  @child = Child.find(params[:id])
end
```

You'll also create your forms with both resources

```
form_for [@parent, @child] do
```